# Uninstalled Lighttpd, installed apache and PHP. PHP not executing

Tags: raspbian-stretch, php, apache-httpd, lighttpd

Title says it all. Lighttpd was automatically installed by [RaspAP](https://github.com/billz/raspap-webgui), a wifi web GUI not being part of Raspbian repository. But I require Apache. Uninstalled Lighttpd, Installed apache with PHP & MySQL. None of my .php files are executing.

I've skimmed php.ini but can't see any config line that may relate.

Comment: What operating system you are using? Seems not to be a Raspbian version because it does not know anything about *RaspAP* in its repository.

Comment: Sorry, should have said. Raspbian Stretch. RaspAP is a wifi web GUI, automatically installs LIGHTTPD

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is needed to customize your installation to *RaspAP* (not the other way around) because it occupies your setup. There ist a [FAQ from RaspAP](https://github.com/billz/raspap-webgui/wiki/FAQs). One point is:

> My custom rc.local/networking configuration/wpa configuration is gone!
>
> Currently, RaspAP generates a few of its own files so that it starts with a known configuration. Your custom configurations haven't been lost however, they've been moved to the backups directory in /etc/raspap/backups.
>
> Feel free to SSH in to restore those files to their rightful position, however, you may need to ensure that the RaspAP modifications are applied to your own custom configurations.